# KeyboardInterrupt exception explanation

Tags: python, exception, linked-list, keyboardinterrupt

The code that I wrote:

def insert(self, new_element, position):
idx = 1
currentNode = self.head

```
def insert(self, new_element, position): 
   idx = 1 
   currentNode = self.head
   while idx < position:
       if idx == position-1:
           new_element.next = currentNode.next
           currentNode.next = new_element
       else:    
           currentNode = currentNode.next
           idx+=1`
```

If I run this, the terminal hits me with a *insert new_element.next= currentNode.next KeyboardInterrup*, which is inside the **if** statement of insert method. However, if I take out the codes from inside the **else** statement and run the code, it works perfectly. The working method is as follows:

```
def insert(self, new_element, position): 
    idx=1
    currentNode = self.head    
    while idx < position:
        if idx == position-1:
            new_element.next= currentNode.next
            currentNode.next= new_element
        #else statement removed but kept the code inside it  
        currentNode = currentNode.next 
        idx+=1
```

Why is the *KeyboardInterrupt* exception happening and how did I solve it? Is there a better solve than how I did, and if so, why? (Sorry, a lot of questions)

Comment: KeyboardInterrupt should only happen if you press control-C while the code is running.  Did you do that?

Comment: [KeyboardInterrupt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt) documentation

Comment: @JohnGordon Nope. I used the terminal given by Udacity, as it is a problem from one of their exercises.

Answer (score 0):

```
while idx < position:
    if idx == position-1:
        new_element.next = currentNode.next
        currentNode.next = new_element
    else:    
        currentNode = currentNode.next
        idx+=1
```

If `idx == position-1` is true, the loop will run forever because `idx` will not be incremented any further.

I suspect the KeyboardInterrupt is happening because Udacity decided that your program was taking too long to run, and used that mechanism to kill it.

I think you meant to have the `idx+=1` line unindented, so it will execute regardless of whether the `if` is true.